# Having trouble getting lower fat fluffy pancakes with baking soda approach

Tags: baking-soda, low-fat, pancakes

I have a baking soda and vinegar pancake recipe that uses too much butter for my liking. When I reduced the butter content, the pancakes seemed too thin and crisp. I tried yogurt, but they seemed too heavy and didn't rise enough. Any suggestions on how I can get a fluffy, light pancake?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try to increase the fluffiness of your pancakes is to separate the egg whites from the yolks so that you can incorporate more air into the batter.  Gently combine all off the ingredients except the whites, whip the whites to stiff peaks, and then gently fold the whites into the rest of the batter.

Comment: Mmm souffle-style pancakes. My favorite. Additional tip: add some baking powder as well. It guarantees a little extra lift if your baking soda is a bit old. Active-culture buttermilk can be substituted for the Vinegar/Yogurt for a better taste with the same effect.